# Segmentation Fault changing Loader's source

Tags: qt, segmentation-fault, qml

I am facing a really weird issue changing the source of a `Loader` with a `ListElement` (of a `ListModel`).
How to reproduce it:

1. Set the source of the loader `loader.source = "Page1.qml"`
2. Change again the loader source `loader.setSource("Page2.qml",
   listModel.get(0))`
3. Finally change again the source like in the first step:
   `loader.source = "Page1.qml"`
4. Segfault will show up.

[image]

Here is the code:

main.qml

```
Window {
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480
    title: qsTr("Hello World")

    Button {
        id: button
        text: qsTr("Load page 1")
        onClicked: mainLoader.source="Page1.qml"
    }

    Loader {
        anchors.left: button.right
        id: mainLoader
        width: 149
        height: 101
    }
}
```

Page1.qml

```
Rectangle {
    color: "red"
    width: 149
    height: 101

    ListModel {
        id: lmIcs
        ListElement {
            code: "1"
            name: "Abdelilah"
            lastname: "El Aissaoui"
        }
    }

    Button {
        text: "Load page 2"
        onClicked: mainLoader.setSource("Page2.qml", lmIcs.get(0))
    }
}
```

Page2.qml

```
Rectangle {
    color: "lightgray"
    width: 149
    height: 101

    property int code;
    property string name;
    property string lastname;

    Text {
        text: code + " - " + name + " " + lastname
    }
}
```

I've noticed that chaning the line that loads the page2 with hardcoded values will make the segfault disappear but obviously this is not a solution:

```
onClicked: mainLoader.setSource("Page2.qml", {code: "1", name: "Abdelilah", lastname: "El Aissaoui" })
```

Is this a bug or am I doing something wrong?

If it helps, I'm using Linux mint 17.3 and compiling with CLang and GCC.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, think about what you are doing:

- you are using only one loader
- you load the component that contains your data model into it
- that component loads another component into the loader that references the model
- the object that has the model is destroyed and replaced by the one that references the now destroyed model

Of course you are going to get a crash. You literally pull the rug from under QML.

And it doesn't crash if you set literal values because that doesn't reference the model.

You should use a `StackView` instead. The newly open page will not replace the item that has the loader but simply be pushed on top of it, until it is destroyed, returning you back to the previous page in the state you left it.

Comment: I thought it but it is really weird that the crash appears when you change the Loader source and not when the second page loads

Comment: @AbdelilahElAissaoui **when** it happens depends on the QML internals, **why** it happens has already been explained. You pass a model item, which is a JS object, which is in fact kept alive after the model is destroyed by that extra reference. But when you set another source, it has to "unset" the previous source, which it runs into the now dangling reference to `lmIcs`.

Comment: Hmmm okay. I've tried with StackView and it works perfectly. Thanks!